# How to pass custom values to Color.rgb(red: 0,green: 0,blue: 0)

Tags: android, android-color

I have to mix colors in a view.Therefore I want to pass custom values to Color.rgb(0,0,255) function

Using Integer Variable will solve the above issue, But I am not able to pass the incremented value to my view.

A little description of what I want to do is:

View v; //to show the color by function Color.rgb()

int red,green,blue; //to change values of R,G,B respectively
int selectedColor = Color.rgb(red, green, blue) //used variable for color
v.setBackground(selectedColor)

//let's say I am increasing red value
Button add; // to increase red value
Button Sub; //to decrease red value

Now, I am stuck with the thing that when I am incrementing the value of red in onClick() function that value is not passing to {selectedColor = Color.rgb(red, green,blue)}. After Incrementing the value of red variable how to pass this red value to selectedColor Variable.?

Comment: What is your problem? Use `Color.rgb()`

Comment: Yes, you should be able to just invoke that function passing in the specific values you desire.  Possibly a code snippet of your implementation thus far would help uncover what the issue is.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Ya. passing integer parameter to Color.rgb() solved my problem. Thanks for all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use

```
Color.rgb()
```

or if you need to use alpha channel use

```
Color.argb()
```